# Enzyme Unit tests with Webpack Externals

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chai, enzyme

I'm currently testing a component that relies on a an external script with webpack externals.

DBPanel.js:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

And the webpack externals file looks like this:

webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
    jquery: "jQuery",
    Materialize: "Materialize"
}
```

When I import the the file in my test `import DBPanel from '../components/DBPanel';` I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
```

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655678/how-to-test-a-webpack-bundle-that-has-external-dependencies