# Correct way to mock webpack "externals" (i.e. jquery) in Vue unit tests (using mocha)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, webpack

I have a Vue project which was created using Vue CLI v3.5 and am trying to write some component unit tests. I have jquery as a webpack external in vue.config.js as follows:

```
...
configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery'
    }
  }
...
```

and I load jquery from a CDN in a script tag in index.html. Obviously whenever I run `vue-cli-service test:unit` I get the following error since jquery isn't a dependency in the project:

```
 RUNTIME EXCEPTION  Exception occurred while loading your tests

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.jquery (.../public/webpack:/external "jQuery":1:1)
...
```

I realize in my unit tests I should probably mock jquery somewhere, but I'm not sure what's the correct way to do this so I only do it in one place within the testing config.

Comment: another unanswered question with same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724728/enzyme-unit-tests-with-webpack-externals

Comment: another unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655678/how-to-test-a-webpack-bundle-that-has-external-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue.js (as I see you've tagged your question thus), I created my own `vue.config.js` as is shown below.

Basically, it marks *jquery* as an external in development/production mode, and resolves it to a mocked version in *test* mode.
Creating a mocked-up version of jquery I'll leave to you though. This example was adapted from a project that uses a different library.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack() {
    const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';

    let resolve;
    let externals = { jquery: 'jquery ' };

    if (isTest) {
      externals = {};

      resolve = {
        alias: {
          // you may have to fiddle around with this path, from the point of view of where jquery is imported
          jquery: './tests/helpers/fakeJQuery.js',
        }
      };
    }

    return {
      resolve,
      externals,
    };
  },
};
```